# UPDATE está inserindo ao invés de atualizando

Tags: php

Eu estou fazendo um crud no PHP e estou tentando fazer a parte do UPDATE, mas quando eu edito um cadastro ele insere ao invés de atualizar e não consigo encontrar o meu erro. Poderiam me ajudar???

```
function atualizarLivros($dadosLivros, $id){

 $id = $dadosLivros['id'];
    
    if(!empty($dadosLivros)) 
    {      
       
        
        if (!empty($dadosLivros['txtNome']) && !empty($dadosLivros['txtEditora']) && !empty($dadosLivros['txtIdioma']) && empty($dadosLivros['txtAutor'])  && !empty($dadosLivros['txtQtspaginas']) && !empty($dadosLivros['txtResumo'])) 
        {
            if(!empty($id) && $id !=0 && is_numeric($id)){ 

                $arrayDados = array(
                    "id"            => $id,     
                    "nome"          => $dadosLivros['txtNome'],
                    "editora"       => $dadosLivros['txtEditora'],
                    "idioma"        => $dadosLivros['txtIdioma'],
                    "Autor"         => $dadosLivros['txtAutor'],
                    "qtsPaginar"    => $dadosLivros['txtQtspaginas'],
                    "resumo"        => $dadosLivros['txtResumo']
                ); 

                
        
     
        require_once('./model/bd/livros.php');
  
            if (updateLivros($arrayDados))  
                return true; 
                         
                else 
                return array ('idErro' => 1, 
                              'message'=>'Não foi possível atualizar os dados');
                           
          } else 
                return array ('idErro' => 2,
                              'message'=> 'Existem campos obrigatórios que não foram preenchidos');

        }
    }
 
}


function updateLivros($dadosLivros)
{

        $conexao = conexaoMysql();

        $sql = "update tblbiblioteca set
                    nome     =    '" . $dadosLivros['nome'] . "',
                    editora      = '" . $dadosLivros['editora'] . "',
                    idioma       = '" . $dadosLivros['idioma'] . "',
                    Autor        = '" . $dadosLivros['Autor'] . "',
                    qtsPaginar   = '" . $dadosLivros['qtsPaginar'] . "',
                    resumo       = '" .$dadosLivros ['resumo'] ."',
                where id         =  " .$dadosLivros['id'];

                
         
      
        if (mysqli_query($conexao, $sql)) {
          
            //Validação para verificar se uma linha foi acrescentada no BD
            if (mysqli_affected_rows($conexao))
                $statusResposta = true;
            else
                $statusResposta = false;
        } else {
            $statusResposta = false;
        }

        fecharConexaoMySql($conexao);
        return $statusResposta;
}
```

Comment: Pergunta bem básica: você tem **certeza** que é o método `updateLivros` que está executando? Se sim, como verificou isso?

Comment: Queira seguir as instruções dadas no campo de comentários [da primeira vez que fez a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/559865/70). Para evitar duplicação de informações e orientações o espaço de comentários daqui foi desativado (o da postagem original não tem restrições se restaurada), mas você pode **restaurar e editar a postagem original** que ela é reavaliada e pode eventualmente vir a ser reaberta pela comunidade.